# iOS app localization

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, unity-game-engine

I want to localize my app. Should I create a new app in itunesconnect for each country or there is a way to automatically detect the country where user is? Actually my app is game based on Unity3d - is it possible to do it on Unity3d?

Comment: I think You Question is like this. [Here is the link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984223/iphone-app-localization-by-releasing-separate-apps-for-different-markets

Comment: There are some localization assets for sale in the asset store that will help you in the Unity part. Saved many hours of my work...

Comment: Here you can find a small tutorial: http://www.delitestudio.com/2012/09/11/how-to-internationalize-an-os-x-ios-app/

Answer (score 2):

Before Unity starts write these lines to pass the current language into unity

```
NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSArray* languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

NSString* preferredLang = [languages objectAtIndex:0];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: preferredLang forKey: @"language"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely don't create a new app for each locale. iOS apps are localizable and iTunes Connect allows you to enter different metadata for each language.

Comment: It's metadata, but I'm intrested in internal content localization, like buttons and etc.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to make a new app for each language. Try following a guide like [SmoothLocalize's tutorial](http://smoothlocalize.com/tutorial1.php) or [This one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial).

Then you'll have a Localizable.strings file you need to translate. I usually use SmoothLocalize.com as my translation services, because its cheap and super easy, but you can look around for others or even try to find individual translators yourself.