# iOS: Can I distribute different .ipa files in different country in APP store

Tags: ios, localization, ipa

Can I upload different .ipa files for one APP in Apple APP store? So that people in different countries can download different .ipa files.

For example:
When people in USA download this APP, they will get app-usa.ipa;
When people in England download this APP, they will get app-england.ipa;
...

All the app-usa.ipa and app-england.ipa are the different build versions of a same APP.

I went through the upload process in iTunes Connect, and didn't find a way to achieve this.

So is it possible to distribute different .ipa files in different countries?
Thank you!

Comment: I found another usefull discussion here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984223/iphone-app-localization-by-releasing-separate-apps-for-different-markets Hope it can help more people:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I can think to do this would be to create different apps with separate names and Bundle IDs for each country, and then set each app to only be available in the country that you created it for. This is, however, against Apple's Guidelines (see comment below).

Realistically, you should develop one app that supports multiple languages and locations and make it available in the countries you intend to provide content for.

Comment: Apple does not allow it though. App Store Review Guidelines: Item 2.20 Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar Apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

Comment: Your second point still holds true. One should support multiple languages or locations with just one app.

Comment: Yeah, I think that would be the solution preferred by Apple.